# How many space suit types could be used at the ISS when Starliner, Crew Dragon and Soyuz are all active?

Tags: spacesuits, record

I just watched the CBS news video [SpaceX and Boeing competing to capture the American flag in space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VcBMr-8moc) about the "race to bring the flag home". It got me wondering about the variety of suits.

I lose track of how many types of space suits are associated with the ISS currently. I think there are two; one for coming and going, and the other for EVA. Now with the possibility of Starliner and Crew Dragon capsules both possibly bringing astronauts to the ISS in 2019, does that make four types of suits?

With CSA and Tiangong-2 counted as well, would the total number of active suits in the near future then be five?

Comment: Do you count the suits in the Soyuz as spacesuit? They don’t go to space.

Comment: @Antzi I tried to word it such that any suit "associated with the ISS" would count for the first part.  I'm not sure what "They don’t go to space" means though. Do they stop and toss them out the window at 100 km? ;-)

Comment: You want to count both EVA suits as well as suits to be worn only inside a transfer capsule?

Comment: @Uwe If it's a pressure suit and keeps the astronaut alive, then sure!